# Make div non selectable behind the overlay

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

I want to show the overlay over the div. After showing overlay i don't want to allow to select that background div. But when i double click on the over lay that background div is in selectable state.
Can you please any one look into this.
http://jsfiddle.net/fkWn5/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

You can do this by using the user select rules in css and adding this class to the background element once turning on the overlay:

css:

```
.unselectable { 
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

adding the class with jquery:

```
$('#backgrounddiv').addClass('unselectable');
```

**jsfiddle example:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/ghm2N/

**References:**

- [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [question with unselectable css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search_name').on('keyup',
    function() {
        search_name = $(this).val();
        $("#names li:contains('" + search_name + "')").addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
```